How can I suppress ASP.NET WebSocket "Response sent" server console logs?
In my ASP.NET Core 9 web application I make a WebSocket connection from the frontend that is used for various things. For development I also make use of the IISExpress console window to monitor server activities.
Unfortunately, ASP.NET Core 9 decides to log every single WebSocket ping-pong to the IISExpress console window. So, if the WebSocket is ping-ponging at a rate of 10 per second, the console is flooded with the same number of the following message:
Response sent: http://localhost:8088/ws/default with HTTP status 101.0

How can I suppress the logging for WebSocket ping-ponging in ASP.NET Core 9?


Please share your Program.cs file ? And the appsettings.json file.
